# wordpress - display list of posts excluding a specific tag

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to display a list of posts that have a certain tag but don't have another specific tag. For examples, I have tried the following to display a list of posts which have 'animal' tag.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'tag' => 'animal',
        'showposts' => 8
         );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()):
        echo '<table>';
        while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
             the_title(); ?> </a></td>

        endwhile;

    endif;
    wp_reset_query();                     

?>
```

How do we display a list of posts in 'animal' tag but not in 'cat' tag for example?
I am very new with wordpress and just learned to create the custom page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to make use of a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) here to make this work. The normal tag parameters won't do the job.

Just a few notes on your original code

- `showposts` is depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`
- `numberposts` is not valid in `WP_Query`
- Use `wp_reset_postdata()` for `WP_Query`, `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts` which should never ever be used
- You need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` before `endif` just after `endwhile`

You will need something like this

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug', //Can use 'name' if you need to pass the name to 'terms
            'terms'    => 'animal', //Use the slug of the tag
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'cat',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tag__not_in` param ([see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)) but you would need the term_id of the cat tag. So maybe something like this:

```
<?php 
// get term_id of unwanted cat tag for tag__not_in param
$tag = get_term_by('name', 'cat', 'post_tag');

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'tag_slug__in' => array('animal'),
    'tag__not_in' => array($tag->term_id),
    'showposts' => 8
     );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()):
    echo '<table>';
    while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
         the_title(); ?> </a></td>

    endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_query();                     

?>
```

Comment: I don't think `numberposts` is a valid param, probably need to remove that.